# Makefile Produces Errors but Builds Fine?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, recipe

I'm using a makefile to build several programs. Here's the code:

```
SRCS = prog1.c prog2.c prog3.c
TARG = all
CC = gcc
OPTS = -O
LIBS = -lm

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(TARG)

$(TARG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(TARG) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(OPTS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARG)
```

This makefile perfectly generates three prog.o files, but I'm getting one error that is confusing me:

```
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I've done a fair amount of searching and can't find anything relating to my particular problem, so I was wondering if anyone had some insight into what is going on here. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

With `TARG = all`, you have:

```
all: all

all: $(OBJS)
```

Name your program something else, not `all`.

Comment: Is there a solution if he really wants to call his program `all`?

Comment: Then there couldn't be a "build everything" target called `all`. I don't recommend it.

Comment: `I don't recommend it` Well, at least in such simple case, it won't hurt, as `all` supposed to build only a single file. So even after removing the line `all:$(TARG)` `make`, `make all` and `make clean all` will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You have cyclic dependency of `all` depending on `all` (because `TARG` expands to `all`). The dependency graph must be a DAG. change

```
TARG = all
```

to

```
TARG = something
```

Comment: What if he really needs to name his program `all`?

Comment: @Barmar: he doesn't have to have an `all` target. `make` will simply choose the first one, independent of the name. But I would say that it's a bad choice of a name for a program and a surprise to anybody who's used to traditional makefiles.